# Compose - functional programming

Tags: javascript, reduce

I wanted to create my own implementation of compose

This works

```
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f,g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));
```

This not

```
const compose1 = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.reduce((f,g) => f(g(...args)));
```

.

```
const multi = a => x => x*a;
const devide = a => x => x/a;
const add = a => x => x+a;

compose(add(6), multi(4), devide(5))(5); // 10 as expected

compose1(add(6), multi(4), devide(5))(5); // Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
```

Could you explain me why second implementation doesn't work?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: i update question

Comment: It works right to left and it is on purpose

Comment: You should put those clarifications in your question, not just as comments. Such things are often missed as I just did now.

Comment: Yea, I just tried it and it makes sense because that 's how compose should work. I've been away from FP for too long lol

Comment: You could also wrote it like this `const compose = (...fns) => p => fns.reduce((r, e) => e(r), p);` https://jsfiddle.net/dkq11m2e/10/

Comment: Yup, thanks. Nice one. But I don't understand why my version fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const compose = (...fns) => {
  console.log('function', fns);
  return fns.reduce((f,g) => {
    console.log('f and g' , f,g)
    return (...args) => {
      console.log('args is ' , args)
      return f(g(...args));
    }
  })
};

// call with 
compose(add(6), multi(4), devide(5))(5);
```

will yield

```
VM1239:2 function (3) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
VM1239:4 f and g x => x+a x => x*a
VM1239:4 f and g (...args) => {
      console.log('args is ' , args)
      return f(g(...args));
    } x => x/a
VM1239:6 args is  [5]
VM1239:6 args is  [1]
10
```

Which works all fine
do the same with your `compose1`

```
const compose1 = (...fns) => {
  console.log('functions ', fns)
  return (...args) => {
    console.log('args', args)
    return fns.reduce((f,g) => {
      console.log('f and g', f,g)
      return f(g(...args))
    })
  }
};
//called with 
compose1(add(6), multi(4), devide(5))(5)
```

will yield

```
VM1783:2 functions  (3) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
 0: x => x+a
 1: x => x*a
 2: x => x/a
VM1783:4 args [5]
VM1783:6 f and g x => x+a x => x*a
VM1783:6 f and g 26 x => x/a
VM1783:7 Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
    at fns.reduce (<anonymous>:7:14)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at args (<anonymous>:5:16)
    at <anonymous>:1:38
```

so your `f` is now 26 which is not a function :)

Explanation:

```
you called 
f (g (...args)) 
f ( g ( 5 ) )
f ( 5 * a)  // a is 4
f ( 20 )
16 + a //  a is 6
26
```

Comment: OP actually uses `5` as the parameter, so your math doesn't match up with his (you use `4`).

Comment: @EricF. the OP edited his question, so I should edit my answer as well

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought   --  f(g(...args)) --  returns a function. Of course it's not true. Thank you for detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what you needed to to do make your version work:

```
const compose1 = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.reduceRight((res, f) => f(res), fns.pop()(...args))
```

The reason why yours failed is because `reduce` (and `reduceRight`) takes a function with this signature:

```
(previousValue, currentValue) => newPreviousValue
```

#### Explanation:

What happens in your version is that after the first time, reduce calls your function, `newPreviousValue` is now no longer a function, it is now `f(g(...args))` (the result of the last function call), so when reduce tries to "call" that function again, it uses the result of the last call as if it's a function, so you get the error.

If you see the one I have above, `res` is the `previousValue`, which is the result of the last function call, but it is not being used as a function.

#### Further

If you are wondering how come it even succeeded on the first call, well the reason for this is because you did not supply an initial value for `reduce`, so it simply took the first two functions from the list as the parameters for the function, which allowed you to do: `f(g(...args))`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought   --  f(g(...args)) --  returns a function. Of course it's not true. Thank you for detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1):

By expanding the syntax out into multiple lines, you can start to see where the problems are in the second function. You're callings `fns.reduce` where you should be calling `args.reduce`. From there, it still returns a different value so there's most likely some other issues going on, but that's a start.

The console logs in the second should also show that the value of `f` isn't what you're expecting it to be.

Ideally you should only write shorthand for very simple operations, or for things you've already fully tested out in a manner easier to read and test against.

```js
const compose = (...fns) => {
  return fns.reduce((f,g) => {
    console.log('f: ',f,'g: ',g)
    return (...args) => f(g(...args))
  })
 };

const compose1 = (...fns) => {
  return (...args) => {
    return args.reduce((f,g) => { //was fns.reduce
      console.log('f: ',f,'g: ',g)
      return f(g(...args))
    })
  }
}

const multi = a => x => x*a;
const devide = a => x => x/a;
const add = a => x => x+a;

var result1 = compose(add(6), multi(4), devide(5))(5); // 10 as expected
console.log(result1)
var result2 = compose1(add(6), multi(4), devide(5))(5); // Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought   --  f(g(...args)) --  returns a function. Of course it's not true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your `compose1` by breaking it down:

```
const compose1 = (...fns) => {
    // Returns a function that reduces fns each time it is called        
    return (...args) => {
        // Returns the reduction of fns
        return fns.reduce((f,g) => {
            // Returns the result of calling f(g(...args))
            return f(g(...args))
        })
    }
};
```

Now lets go through a sample call of this version of compose:

```
compose1(add(6), multi(4), devide(5))(5);
```

First, we call `compose1`. This returns this function:

```
(...args) => {
    // Returns the reduction of fns
    return fns.reduce((f,g) => {
        // Returns the result of calling f(g(...args))
        return f(g(...args))
    })
}
```

We then call this function with a parameter of `5`, which is essentially calling `fns.reduce` as in the previously returned function. To see what exactly is going wrong, let's run through a few iterations of the reduce:

First iteration:

```
fns.reduce((f = add(6), g = multi(4)) => {
    // Returns the result of calling f(g(...args))
    return f(g(...args = [5]))
    // g is `multi(4)`, so do `multi(4)(5)`, which returns 20. Next:
    // f is `add(6)`, so do `add(6)(20)`, which returns 26.
    // Remember that the return from last iteration is
    //   the first parameter of the next iteration
})
```

Second iteration:

```
fns.reduce((f = 26, g = devide(5)) => {
    // Returns the result of calling f(g(...args))
    return f(g(...args = [5]))
    // g is `devide(5)`, so do `devide(5)(5)`, which returns 1. Next:
    // f is 26, so do `26(1)`. However, 26 is not a function.
    // You get the error `f is not a function`.
})
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought   --  f(g(...args)) --  returns a function. Of course it's not true. Thanks for detailed answer :)